# Split string into equal slices/chunks

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string of length `N` and I want to split it into equal parts of length `L` (assuming the last part might be shorter).

What I came up with is:

```
string.split('').each_slice(L).map(&:join)
```

but this is toooooo long (and too ugly, to be honest.) Am I unable to read the documentation properly, or is there no built-in method to perform this task?

Comment: Rather than describing all that you did about `N` and `NUM_SLICES`, it would be easier if you just presented some length `l` and forget about them.

Comment: Instead of `split('')`, you can also use `chars`

Comment: This also works: `((string.size+L-1)/L).times.map { |i| string[L*i,L] }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
string.scan(/.{,#{L}}/)
```

Comment: Well, it is definitely better, but it is still far from being semantically clear.

Comment: I thought this was pretty clear, and it also uses only one method. A similar regex is also used in Rails for separating a line in to several lines.

Comment: When I run this, I always get and empty string as the last item in the array.

Comment: Scan only returns __matching__ tokens. If last element is not equal length L it will be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, it would be better to use `split`, not `scan`.

```
string.split(/.{,#{L}}/)
```

`scan` used where need to get **exact** pattern from the string, and it will skip the last part of the text since it will be shorter than `L` in most cases.

And here is the example if you want to keep word boundary:

```
string.split(/(.{1,#{L}})(?:\s|$)/)
```